# Threejs transparent Scene with transparent Shapes

Tags: javascript, three.js, shapes, transparent

i have a Problem to make this scene working:
Snow Flakes in front of a html body.

I created a basic scene with WebGLRenderer and alpha true, set the clear color, ... then i load the png files of my snowflakes.

Problem: the transparent background depends on the  scene body background, so it is displayed black for basic, but it should be transparent.

Here a link for sample
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqg9ovicbh0w1ox/Kalender.rar?dl=0

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/End0rph1ne/3ddsjh07/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Make sure your snowflake textures have a transparent background. Try `snowflake7_alpha.png` instead. Or test with `disc.png`.

Comment: Thee Files are definitely transparent

Comment: No. West Langley is correct, your sprite images are not transparent. Open just this in your browser: https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprites/snowflake1.png The snowflake you're using has a black background. Also, once you're using using sprites with an alpha layer, ensure you use `transparent: true` in your `THREE.PointsMaterial` definition, otherwise the alpha channel won't be evaluated. Finally, please post relevant code along with your jsfiddle link. In the event your fiddle goes away, the code will remain here for future readers.